# How to set nginx by IP server without domain, problem with tutorial

Tags: nginx

I tried to do this tutorial with simple flask app using nginx and gunicorn https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

and i got problems with last step - how to correctly set IP but not domain address at /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject ? I got only IP, when i used just previous steps with IP:5000 its works well with gunicorn and flask, and now when i tried to complete it together its doesnt work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I tried to use server_name IP; and listen IP; but no effect. What i do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: write `server_name n.n.n.n;` then the ip will be the hostname.

Comment: Is it a public server, or only for you local LAN network?

Comment: Its not local its VPS, thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you do not have a domain name to use, you can just set the `server_name` as the IP itself, like:

```
server_name 10.0.0.1;
```

As long as your port is open, the service is running, and the IP is reachable from your source - this will work fine.

A good test is to simply curl the port from the local machine where nginx is running:

```
curl http://localhost:80/
```

If this returns what you expect - then the chances are your IP is not reachable from whatver source you are hitting from on the outside.

**tips**

- Check your IP is reachable from your source with a `telnet` or something similar
- Is any firewalls blocking your port? If this is AWS or Azure, take a look at the inbound rules.
- What response do you get from the browser? if you get something like `bad request` then it's safe to assume nginx is working fine but your proxy pass is service something wrong.

Comment: Im using VPS ubuntu,

Comment: Its doesnt work when i create server_name IP; - that a problem, maybe there is a error in tutorial?

Comment: You have to access it with the same `server_name`, like `curl http://10.0.0.1:80/`